# proof of composition of Taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial, let $[p(x)]_k$ be the truncation of $p(x)$ at degree $k$ (i.e., drop all terms of degree higher than $k$). Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are $(n + 1)$-times continuously differentiable.

Prove: If $g(0) = 0$, $T_n f ◦ g(x) = [T_n f ◦ T_n g(x)]_n$.

Any help would be nice.

$T_n$ is another way to say Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ and I know how to show this with two examples but I cannot create a general proof.

Comment: What is $Tn$? Also, have you tried something and gotten stuck, and what is your current thought process on the problem?

Comment: I think that the $n$ should be subscript: $T_n$. There's also an established notion: $J_x^n f$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics))